# Sparse Hessian for FindMinimum? Broken?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Is the sparse Hessian mechanism for FindMinimum[] (Method->"Newton") broken? Or am I simply not apprehending its proper setup?  Here's what's happening.

Below is for solving the example problem given in 
  tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodMinimum#509267359
using specified Gradient g and (dense) Hessian h functions.

The only difference here from the documentation example is I specify g and h as bare symbolic expressions using RuleDelayed rather than as functions with x_?NumberQ type arguments. Nonetheless, the correct result is obtained:

```
Clear[f, g, h, x, y]
f = Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + Sin[x^2 + y^2]    
g = D[f, {{x, y}}]

(* Out[3]= {2 x Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 2 x Sin[x^2 - 3 y], 2 y Cos[x^2 + y^2]  + 3 Sin[x^2 - 3 y]}  *)

h = D[f, {{x, y}, 2}]    
(* Out[4]= {{-4 x^2 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 
2 Sin[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2]}, 
{6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2],
-9 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 4 y^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2]}} *)

FindMinimum[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, Method -> {"Newton", 
"Hessian" :> {h, "EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[h]}}, 
Gradient :> {g, "EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[g]}]

(* Output: 
{0.986301,-3.56019}
{{-0.986301,-6.13407},{-6.13407,-0.724162}}
{-0.527482,2.63714}
{{12.3165,2.2687},{2.2687,20.8245}}
{0.230844,-0.059627}
{{15.6441,0.981772},{0.981772,20.2644}}
{0.00357296,0.0000289779}
{{15.1633,0.983822},{0.983822,20.2729}}
{9.20305*10^-7,7.95904*10^-9}
{{15.1555,0.983708},{0.983708,20.2718}}
{5.85103*10^-14,2.82458*10^-15}
{{15.1555,0.983708},{0.983708,20.2718}}}
Out[5]= {-2., {x -> 1.37638, y -> 1.67868}}  *)
```

Now onto replicating the above, but this time specifying a sparse Hessian. I attempt to follow the setup discussed in:
 tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSpecifyingDerivatives#562305099

We first obtain the sparse Hessian function (sparhess), per the cells below:
    1. convert the dense 2D list-based Hessian into a SparseArray form,
    2. perform the indepotent Transpose[Transpose to force consistent lexicographic array index ordering of the non-zero element Rules
    3. obtain those ArrayRules to form our sparse Hessian function, which is a same-ordered 1D list of the non-zero element functions...
    4. ... parsing out the RHS expression of each Rule, and omitting the last ArrayRule, which is the default value for "zero" elements:

```
sphess = SparseArray[h];
sparsity = Transpose[Transpose[sphess]];
arhess = ArrayRules[sparsity]    
(* Out[8]={{1, 1} -> -4 x^2 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 
2 Sin[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
{1, 2} -> 6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
{2, 1} -> 6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2],
{2, 2} -> -9 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 4 y^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
{_, _} -> 0}  *)

sparhess = arhess[[1 ;; -2, 2]]
(* Out[9]= {-4 x^2 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 
2 Sin[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2], 
6 x Cos[x^2 - 3 y] - 4 x y Sin[x^2 + y^2],
-9 Cos[x^2 - 3 y] + 2 Cos[x^2 + y^2] - 4 y^2 Sin[x^2 + y^2]}
```

Next, we obtain the "SparseArray template" (sparsity) which specifies the sparsity pattern (non-zero elements) of the Hessian, per the cells below:
    1. Take our earlier ArrayRules (arhess) and replace the RHS of Rules with Pattern "_", omitting the last ArrayRule, which is the default value for "zero" elements
    2. Form a SparseArray from these ArrayRules
    3. To be safe, do the trick to force consistent internal ArrayRule ordering:

```
arhess = Map[ReplacePart[#, 2 -> _] &, arhess[[1 ;; -2]]]
(* Out[10]= {{1, 1} -> _, {1, 2} -> _, {2, 1} -> _, {2, 2} -> _} *)
sparsity = SparseArray[arhess];
sparsity = Transpose[Transpose[sparsity]];
```

Now finally onto employing this in FindMinimum:

```
FindMinimum[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, Method -> {"Newton", 
"Hessian" :>  {sparhess, "Sparse" -> sparsity, 
"EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[sparhess]}}, 
Gradient :> {g, "EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[g]}]

(* Output: 
{0.986301,-3.56019}
{-0.986301,-6.13407,-6.13407,-0.724162}
{-9.46857,-4.5823}
{-13.6137,-3.30307}
{0.0908205,0.636614}
{1.36673,-0.619934,-0.619934,6.60192} 
{-0.111213,-0.102242}
{2.29398,0.384308,0.384308,7.15042}
{-0.00442004,-0.00834982}
{2.19695,0.0162966,0.0162966,7.16648}
{-0.0000188381,-0.0000167613}
{2.18754,0.000069903,0.000069903,7.16556}
{-1.63506*10^-10,-3.03399*10^-10}
{2.18752,6.06735*10^-10,6.06735*10^-10,7.16555}
Out[13]= {-0.179902, {x -> -7.47451*10^-11, y -> 0.905726}}  *)
```

**Wrong Answer!**  Comparing the gradient and hessian values printout for this FindMinimum run to the earlier correct run, we see that the first gradient and Hessian values are identical, but then our sparse version goes off the rails.

Interestingly, rerunning the above as so, *using our original dense Hessian h to drive the minimization*, setting "Sparse" to False, *but along the minimization path printing out the values of sparhess*, we observe the correct values being computed from sparhess (!?):

```
FindMinimum[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, Method -> {"Newton", 
"Hessian" :>  {h, "Sparse" -> False, 
"EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[sparhess]}}, 
Gradient :> {g, "EvaluationMonitor" :>  Print[g]}]

(* Output: 
{0.986301,-3.56019}
{-0.986301,-6.13407,-6.13407,-0.724162}
{-0.527482,2.63714}
{12.3165,2.2687,2.2687,20.8245}
{0.230844,-0.059627}
{15.6441,0.981772,0.981772,20.2644}
{0.00357296,0.0000289779}
{15.1633,0.983822,0.983822,20.2729}
{9.20305*10^-7,7.95904*10^-9}
{15.1555,0.983708,0.983708,20.2718}
{5.85103*10^-14,2.82458*10^-15}
{15.1555,0.983708,0.983708,20.2718}
Out[14]= {-2., {x -> 1.37638, y -> 1.67868}}  *)
```

Comment: I'm missing something here. Your Hessian is manifestly not sparse, so why are you forcing it to become a `SparseArray[]`? Or, is this a toy example, and something similar happens to your actual application?

Comment: Could you clean up your code so one can copy/paste it? Remove all the In/Out statements, remove output or format as comments, etc. Also take a look at this link: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951)

Comment: Hi J. M.  Yes, this is a toy example only.  My actual application (20K variables) has a very sparse Hessian, and using the suggested method in documentation, my result is an overflow upon the first step (g and h EvalMonitors fire then overflow).

Comment: Hi MarcoB -- will do now.

Comment: Hi again J. M.  I should also indicate that using QuasiNewton method, I obtain an okay solution.

Comment: I think if you check the "wrong answer," you will find it is a local minimum.  Therefore it is technically a "right answer."  The `SparseArray` approach seems to take a funny first step that lands in a different basin than the default.  I haven't been able to figure why the initial step is off.  (Monitor with `EvaluationMonitor :> Print[eval[x, y, f]], StepMonitor :> 
 Print[step[x, y, f]]`, if `eval` and `step` are undefined.)

Comment: Hi Michael.  Good point!  I Plot3D'd f, identified a starting point {1.5,1.5} which was unambiguously in the one "correct" basin of attraction, re-executed the SparseArray version, and it found the "correct" answer.  As you indicate, it's mystifying as to why the dense and sparse versions take different steps when there should be no difference.  That difference remains the only "smoking run" to why my full-scale problem overflows.  I checked my full-scale numerical entries of gradient and hessian and none of the values would indicate ill-conditioning.  Ugh!

Comment: One clue is that FindMinimumPlot goes haywire (eating 6GB RAM so far before Abort) on the SparseArray version.

Comment: It also doesn't help that FindMinimumPlot is not behaving per docs (tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationPlottingSearchData), where even with the provided example Newton method, it is NOT reporting Hessian evals.  (This is version 10.1).

Comment: @frankeye It's not clear to me that `FindMinimum` might not take a slightly different approach with the sparse array method. I don't **know** how the method works, but there may be general issues with a sparse system.  For instance, at the initial point `{1., 1.}` in the simple example, the Hessian is not positive definite, which it should be near a minimum.  In sparse systems, it might in general be good to search for better starting point.

Comment: The same behaviors all observed for version 10.2 as in 10.1

Comment: Have you tried constraining the variables?  (If appropriate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't be sure what `FindMinimum` does.  I can only find the various `*Monitor` options to see what major steps it takes.  Then I might only infer, rightly or wrongly, why it does any of these things.  I will say that I think it is behaving "correctly" in the sense of "as intended."

When all the conditions are "right," [the step taken by `FindMinimum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodMinimum.html) under Newton's method is given by

```
LinearSolve[h, -g, Method -> {"Cholesky", "Modification" -> "Minimal"}]
```

where `h` denotes the Hessian and `g` the gradient of `f`.  The Hessian matrix `h` needs to be "sufficiently positive definite" for `CholeskyDecomposition`.  But `LinearSolve` returns an answer whether or not `h` is positive definite, and sometimes `FindMinimum` accepts it when `h` is not.  I also suspect that this is only an approximate description of what happens.  For instance, there are internal functions that might be used:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One thought is that sparse systems, which typically have a large number of variables, exhibit certain issues in general, and `FindMinimum` might be applying a different strategy than on a small dense system.  It may also automatically apply sparse methods to sparse input that is neither large nor sparse.

It does seem that the OP has set up the sparse Hessian correctly, and it works as expected in a basin in which the Hessian is positive definite (which is typical of local minima, except in pathological cases).

**Analysis of the example**

(See below for auxiliary functions `fmdata`, which gathers data about the steps `FindMinimum` takes and `fmdataplot` which plots it.)

Below are the steps `FindMinimum` takes on the basic example.  The black arrow indicates the direction of the gradient at the initial point, and the green arrow is the step at the initial point predicted by `LinearSolve`.  In this case it is the step `FindMinimum` takes.

```
fm0 = fmdata@ FindMinimum[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, 
    Method -> {"Newton", "Hessian" :> h}, Gradient :> g];
plot = fmdataplot[fm0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below is the same plot for the sparse method. Note the step by `LinearSolve` would be identical, but `FindMinimum` ignores it (as though it did not even bother to compute it).

```
fmsp = fmdata@ FindMinimum[f, {{x, 1}, {y, 1}}, 
    Method -> {"Newton", "Hessian" :> {sparhess, "Sparse" -> sparsity}}, Gradient :> g];
fmdataplot[fmsp]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What has happened is that `FindMinimum` went far to the left and searched back toward the initial point, apparently looking for a point where the Hessian is positive definite.  This can be seen in the points that are evaluated (the points in red are the initial point plus the actual steps; the black pairs are extra evaluations done to determine the next step):

```
fmsp["eval"] /. (# -> Style[#, Red] & /@ fmsp["steps"])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we manually apply the `LinearSolve` step first, the sparse method follows the default method, probably because the step lands in a basin where the Hessian is positive definite.

```
fmsp1 = Module[{x0, y0},
   {x0, y0} = {1., 1.} + 
     LinearSolve[
      h /. Thread[{x, y} -> {1., 1.}], -g /. Thread[{x, y} -> {1., 1.}], 
      Method -> {"Cholesky", "Modification" -> "Minimal"}];
   fmdata@
    FindMinimum[f, {{x, x0}, {y, y0}}, 
     Method -> {"Newton", "Hessian" :> {sparhess, "Sparse" -> sparsity}}, Gradient :> g]
   ];
Show[fmdataplot[fmsp1], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1, 1}]}], 
  PlotRange -> PlotRange[plot]] /. 
 gc_GraphicsComplex :> Cases[plot, _GraphicsComplex, Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Code dump**

Aside from `fmdata` and `fmdataplot` used above, I include two more

- `fmLSsteps`, which computes the steps predicted by `LinearSolve`, which can be compared with the actual steps taken by `FindMinimum`.
- `fmLSstepgraphics`, which creates an arrow for each step representing the predicted step.

The data structure returned by `fmdata` is an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) with the following keys:

- `"result"`: The result of `FindMinimum`
- `"eval"`: The points where the function was evaluated (from `EvaluationMonitor`)
- `"steps"`: The steps taken (points, from `StepMonitor`)
- `"variables"`: The variables passed to `FindMinimum`
- `"initialpoint"`: The initial point passed to `FindMinimum`
- `"function"`: The function passed to `FindMinimum`
- `"gradient"`: The gradient used (computed with `D`)
- `"hessian"`: The Hessian used (computed with `D`)
- `"method"`: The `Method` option passed to `FindMinimum`

The function `fmdataplot` is used instead of `` Optimization`UnconstrainedProblems`FindMinimumPlot `` because `FindMinimumPlot` did not work with the sparse method.  It would never finish.  There is an optional second argument

```
fmdataplot[data, points]
```

where `points` can be either "steps" or "eval"; it determines whether to plot the steps or the evaluation points.  The default is `"steps"`.

```
ClearAll[fmdata, fmdataplot, fmLSsteps, fmLSstepgraphics];
SetAttributes[fmdata, HoldAll];
fmdata[FindMinimum[obj_, init_List, opts : OptionsPattern[FindMinimum]]] := 
  Module[{f, g, h, var, var0, min, ptsS, ptsE},
   f = First@Flatten[{obj}];
   var = init[[All, 1]];
   var0 = N@init[[All, 2]];
   g = D[f, {var}];
   h = D[f, {var, 2}];
   {min, {{ptsS}, {ptsE}}} = Reap[
     Sow[var0, "step"]; (* add step 0 *)
     FindMinimum[obj, init,
      StepMonitor :> Sow[var, "step"], 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[var, "eval"],
      opts
      ],
     {"step", "eval"}
     ];
   <|"result" -> min, "eval" -> ptsE, "steps" -> ptsS, 
    "variables" -> var, "initialpoint" -> var0, "function" -> f, 
    "gradient" -> g, "hessian" -> h, 
    "method" -> OptionValue[FindMinimum, {opts}, Method]|>];
fmdataplot[data_, pts_: "steps"] := 
 With[{p0 = data@"initialpoint", 
    eval = Thread[data@"variables" -> data@"initialpoint"]},
  MinMax /@ Transpose[data[pts]] /. {{x1_, x2_}, {y1_, y2_}} :>
    Show[
     ContourPlot[data["function"], {x, x1 - 0.3, x2 + 0.3}, {y, y1 - 0.3, y2 + 0.3}],
     Graphics[{{PointSize[Large], Thick,
          Line[#, VertexColors -> ColorData[{"Rainbow",{1,Length@#}}] /@ Range[Length@#]],              
          Point[#,VertexColors -> ColorData[{"Rainbow",{1,Length@#}}] /@ Range[Length@#]],
          Red, 
          MapIndexed[
           Text[First@#2, #1, 
             2.5 {Cos[1.5 First@#2], Sin[1.5 First@#2]}] &, #]} &[
        data@pts],
       Tooltip[
        Arrow[{p0, 
          p0 - 0.1 Sqrt[(x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2]*Normalize@data@"gradient" /. eval}],
        "gradient"],
       Green, 
       Tooltip[Arrow[{p0, 
          p0 + LinearSolve[data@"hessian" /. eval, -data@"gradient" /. eval, 
            Method -> {"Cholesky", "Modification" -> "Minimal"}]}], 
        "LS step"]}]
     ]
  ]
fmLSsteps[data_, pts_: "steps"] := LinearSolve[
     data@"hessian" /. Thread[data@"variables" -> #],
     -data@"gradient" /. Thread[data@"variables" -> #], 
     Method -> {"Cholesky", "Modification" -> "Minimal"}] & /@ 
   data[pts];
fmLSstepgraphics[data_, pts_: "steps"] := MapThread[
  Tooltip[Arrow[{#, # + #2}], "LS step"] &,
  {data@pts, fmLSsteps[data, pts]}]
```

*Example of `fmLSstepgraphics`:*
The sparse method steps, with close-up (right).  One can see the first step is different, but inside the basin, the steps agree.

```
GraphicsRow[{
  foo = Show[fmdataplot[fmsp], 
    Graphics[{Green, fmLSstepgraphics[fmsp]}]],
  Show[foo, PlotRange -> ({-0.1, 0.1} + # & /@ fmsp["result"][[2, All, 2]])]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't have a way to answer about the OP's concern with overflow in the OP's use-case.  The actual code probably has to be given.  It certainly could have to do with the actual functions used.  It could have to do with the large steps taken at first.  Perhaps putting constraints on the variables would help.

Comment: @Micheal E2 -- Bravo!  Many thanks!