# What is Hessian?

Tags: options

I was working today and had to calculate the Hessian of a matrix, then I wondered a Hessian function might already exist. I typed `Hessian`
and it does exist, but there's no documentation (neither online nor software embedded) that explains what the heck this function is. `?Hessian` confirms the tag is protected and that it must do something. I'm curious now... Does anyone know what's going on?

**P.S.:** I'm using *Mathematica 10*.

**P.S.2:** I know how to calculate an Hessian.

Comment: Maybe it is a function that will be included  in later versions (or has already been included in some 10.x version?). At the moment there is the name...

Comment: No predefined function. Assuming your function `f` is a function of a vector  (i.e., `f[x1, x2, ..., xn]` use D[f[x1, x2, ...,xn], {{x1, x2, ..., xn}, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks, but defining a function for calculating an Hessian was never the problem. I was interested in the existence of a phantom function I found by accident =)

Comment: Apart for simply being a `Protected` symbol, `PrintDefinitions` (from `GeneralUtilities` package) shows no other definitions attached to it (not even `<<kernel function>>`).  So it does nothing.

Comment: Isn't this strange? Did some programmer mess up? It looks like incomplete work.

Comment: `Names["System *"]` returns 5888 names, many of which have no more associated `Information` than `Hessian` does. Probably, they are internal functions not meant to be called directly.

Comment: `Hessian` (alternatively `"Hessian"`) is an option name. Related: [(91628)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91628), [(98501)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98501), [Newton's method tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodMinimum.html), [derivative tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationSpecifyingDerivatives.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Mathematica documentation for [`FindMaxValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaxValue.html) includes the example

```
FindMaxValue[Sin[x] Sin[2 y], {x, y}, 
 Gradient -> {Cos[x] Sin[2 y], 2 Cos[2 y] Sin[x]}, 
 Method -> {"Newton", 
   Hessian -> {{-Sin[x] Sin[2 y], 
      2 Cos[x] Cos[2 y]}, {2 Cos[x] Cos[2 y], -4 Sin[x] Sin[2 y]}}}]
```

which includes a reference to `Hessian` as part of the `Method`.  I believe that this (and probably other similar usages) will cause it to appear as a symbol in the "System" context.